How to redirect https://typersworld.com/any to https://www.typersworld.com/any using Traefik in Docker Compose?
I'm new to hosting on a VPS and using Traefik. I'm trying to set up a redirection so that requests to https://typersworld.com automatically redirect to https://www.typersworld.com. However, despite trying multiple solutions (mostly from AI chat models), the redirection isn't working, and my website has gone down multiple times during my attempts, affecting my SEO.
Here's my current docker-compose.yaml configuration:  for frontend and traefik
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v3.1
    command:
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=bilalniamani001@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https"
      - "--api=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - backend-net

  frontend:
    image: bilawalnizamani/typing-game-frontend:latest
    env_file:
      - ./frontend.env
    init: true
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - backend-net
    depends_on:
      backend:
        condition: service_healthy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`www.typersworld.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls=true"
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true"
    restart: always
enter code here

Key Issues:
I don’t know how to set up redirection from https://typersworld.com/.... to https://www.typersworld.com/....
or
http://typersworld.com/... to https://www.typersworld.com/...
I’m worried about making mistakes that could bring my website down again.
Could someone please help me set up this redirection properly?
Thanks in advance! Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The http to https redirect is already in place on entrypoint.
Use a middleware to do the redirect to www. Make sure to have both domains in rule=:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.http.routers.mywhoami.rule=Host(`www.example.com`) || Host(`example.com`)
  - traefik.http.routers.mywhoami.middlewares=myredirect
  - traefik.http.middlewares.myredirect.redirectregex.regex=^https://example.com/(.*)
  - traefik.http.middlewares.myredirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://www.example.com/$${1}
  - traefik.http.services.mywhoami.loadbalancer.server.port=80

